# How can a Model be anchored above the user's Head in visionOS?

Tags: swift, swiftui, realitykit, visionos

Let's say for example, I want to anchor a cloud above the user's head.

I know that `AnchorEntity` exists and that you can get a reference to the user's head with `AnchorEntity(.head)`. But how do I actually use it? With this code I am not seeing anything at all.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct CloudSpace: View {
    
    let headAnchor = AnchorEntity(.head)
    
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            async let cloud = ModelEntity(named: "Cloud")
            do {
                content.add(headAnchor)
                let cloud = try await cloud
                headAnchor.addChild(cloud)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Anchoring a Model using Head anchor in visionOS

To see `AnchoringComponent.Target.head` in action, you can use either a real Vision Pro device or Xcode 15 visionOS Simulator. To activate a head's target (also known as `.camera` target in iOS, or `DeviceAnchor` object in ARKit for visionOS), try the following code. But consider the fact that `head` anchor's automatically updated every frame by default – use `.once` tracking mode to change it.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            RealityView { content in

                if let cloud = try? await Entity(named: "Scene",
                                                in: realityKitContentBundle) {

                    let anchor = AnchorEntity(.head)
                    anchor.anchoring.trackingMode = .once
                    cloud.setParent(anchor)
                    content.add(anchor)
    
                    // Z offset is important
                    cloud.transform.translation.z = -1.0  
                    cloud.transform.translation.y = 0.25
                    anchor.name = "Head Anchor"
                    print(content)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's a shame we can't simulate it. I understand hands/fingers but the head is basically just the camera. Hopefully in Beta 3 

Comment: In my testing, if you have it using .continuous it'll work in the simulator at the moment. I'm using Beta 3.

Comment: I wonder if I can get the world position for this cloud when it is a child of the head, cause the normal way to do it using position(relative to:nil) or transform.translation gives a fixed place even though the head moves, you have a solution for that?

Comment: @AhmedEl-Bermawy, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77577395/how-to-know-users-position-in-surrounding-space-in-visionos/77616297#77616297).

Comment: In that post I wrote: "...the AnchorEntity(.head) transformation matrix is ​​currently hidden in visionOS...", I am now sure that it was hidden on purpose, so you need to use VisionOS ARKit to access it.

Comment: @AndyJazz thanx for the post, I already do this in ARKit before using matrix but the problem here that the line  "worldInfo.queryDeviceAnchor(atTimestamp: CACurrentMediaTime()) " gives this error "Trying to get pose for nil service reference"  is it because im using the simulator or because i'm working in immersive view?

Comment: Use Full Space immersiveness.

Comment: @AndyJazz, Thanx I figure it out and I can still use it even in immersive mix the only missing code was to await for the world info task " Task {  try? await session.run([worldInfo]) }" this have to be in the "RealView {content in ....}",

Comment: Sorry, I can't continue our discussion in chat...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just get the position of the head, to place content appropriately for testing, then you can use the `WorldTrackingProvider.queryPose(atTimestamp)`. It will give you the transform of the device at the TimeInterval specified.

It will mean setting up an ARKitSession with WorldTracking. It's also an "expensive" operation according [to the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/worldtrackingprovider/4218774-querypose), but it will at least give you the current head location:

`let pose = worldInfo.queryPose(atTimestamp: CACurrentMediaTime())`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionos/tracking-points-in-world-space/#Track-the-device-position-in-the-world