# Vision Pro window that follows me

Tags: window, visionos

With Vision Pro, if you look up, there is a button that opens a view for selecting apps, control panel, and others. This button will follow you as you move around a room. I want to program a window in my visionOS app that does this, that is, stays in place in my FOV as I move around without me having to hold the window bar.

Can this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76561090/how-can-a-model-be-anchored-above-the-users-head-in-visionos

Comment: Maybe also helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77577395/how-to-know-users-position-in-surrounding-space-in-visionos

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem possible with a normal Window.

> Although you can change the window’s content, you can’t directly manipulate window position or size after the window appears. This ensures that people have full control over their workspace.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionos/positioning-and-sizing-windows

Answer (score 0):

This is supposedly limited to `ImmersiveSpace` with `ImmersionStyle` set to `.full`, to avoid interfering with other apps, which makes sense.

Use `AnchorEntity` and `AnchoringComponent.Target.head`.

Marking this as a "Community wiki" answer, so someone can improve it.

1. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionos/creating-fully-immersive-experiences
2. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/anchorentity
3. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/anchoringcomponent/target-swift.enum/head