# RealityKit track head movement/position?

Tags: swift, swiftui, realitykit, visionos, vision-pro

How can I track the head position (relative from some absolute initial anchor position in space), or the head movement (like mouse movement) from the user wearing the Vision Pro with RealityKit?

My goal is to be able to have both other entities in space mimic the head movement, as well as emitting that data to physical hardware to mimic movement (e.g. camera), so I need to be able to track the position and angle that the head is looking, effectively getting the IMU data from the headset.

Comment: AnchorEntity(.head) you’ll also need World Provider

Answer (score 2):

In visionOS 1.1, RealityKit's [AnchorEntity(.head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76561090/how-can-a-model-be-anchored-above-the-users-head-in-visionos/76561914#76561914) can only help you attach models (with a desired offset) to a device world position. However, the transform matrix of `AnchorEntity(.head)` is hidden by framework's design. To expose Vision Pro's world transform, you need ARKit's DeviceAnchor. Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import ARKit

struct ContentView: View {
    let visionPro = VisionPro()

    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            _ = content.subscribe(to: SceneEvents.Update.self) { _ in
                Task {
                    let x = await visionPro.transformMatrix().columns.3.x
                    let y = await visionPro.transformMatrix().columns.3.y
                    let z = await visionPro.transformMatrix().columns.3.z
                    print(String(format: "%.2f, %.2f, %.2f", x, y, z))
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            await visionPro.runArkitSession()
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
@Observable class VisionPro {
    let session = ARKitSession()
    let worldTracking = WorldTrackingProvider()
    
    func transformMatrix() async -> simd_float4x4 {
        guard let deviceAnchor = worldTracking.queryDeviceAnchor(atTimestamp: .zero)
        else { return .init() }
        return deviceAnchor.originFromAnchorTransform
    }
    
    func runArkitSession() async {
        Task {
            try? await session.run([worldTracking])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to get the 3 degrees of rotation as well? And i"m assuming this is a delta per "tick"?

Comment: To find out what's about rotation, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75430893/extract-translation-rotation-scale-from-simd-float4x4/75432704#75432704), please.

Comment: @danthegoodman, when you don't want to decompose the rotation matrix (it's a challenge), it's easier to pass all 16 values ​​of this matrix from one entity to another.

Comment: and on the transform matrix, is that a sort of tick-delta?

Comment: Which tick-delta do you mean exactly? `Any combination of translation, rotations, scalings and shears can be combined in a single 4 by 4 afﬁne transformation matrix`.

Comment: I guess a more clear question: Is the `content.subscribe(to: SceneEvents.Update.self) { _ in` section the change since the last time it printed, or from some initial anchor? I'm guessing the former.

Comment: Oui, monsieur, the former one.